# Manifest vs ClassManifest. What does this Scala error mean?

Tags: scala, manifest, scala-2.8

What does this error mean?

```
scala> val a = Array[{ def x: Int }](new { def x = 3 }) 
<console>:5: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.reflect.Manifest[java.lang.Object]
 required: scala.reflect.ClassManifest[AnyRef{def x: Int}]
       val a = Array[{ def x: Int }](new { def x = 3 })
                                    ^
```

I don't have a clue ...

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug. val a = List[{ def x: Int }](new { def x = 3 })  works ok.

Comment: @Eric And there's a difference between a `List` and an `Array`, which should be a hint as to what is going on.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, let's consider a couple of things. First:

```
type T = { def x: Int }
```

This type is known as a *structural type*. It defines not a class, but a set of objects that share methods with a certain type signature. At run-time, it is erased to `Object`, and any calls to `x` are done through reflection, since Java doesn't have any equivalent to it.

Next:

```
val a = Array[{ def x: Int }](new { def x = 3 })
```

Note that you did not use `new Array`, but `Array`. That is a call to the `apply` method of Scala's `Array` object. This method requires a `ClassManifest` implicit parameter that will tell Scala how to create the array. This is necessary because *arrays are not erased* in Java, so Scala has to provide the precise type to Java.

And here's the problem: there's no such type in Java.

I do wonder if it wouldn't be possible for Scala to use `Object` here. A ticket might be in order, but don't count on it being possible.

Comment: Is this an example of artefact that would not be there if scala was not JVM language but standalone ?

Comment: @Lukasz It is a limitation imposed by the characteristics of the JVM, though it seems to me that it could be worked around. The way `Array` works nowadays was introduced with Scala 2.8.0, so this might well be the first time someone tried to do something like that.